# How to backup/restore standalone heroku postgres database?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Is there a **Heroku** way to backup / restore a standalone postgres database at https://postgres.heroku.com/ apart from using `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` ? The database is not attached to any app.

I can create a dump using

```
pg_dump --verbose -F c -b -h hostname -p port -U username -f "backup.dump" database_name
```

and restore it using

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h hostname -p port -U username -d database_name "backup.dump"
```

Comment: [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: Won't work as the database is not linked to any app.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any other official way. According to that link, _you will need to first create and configure the app on Heroku before performing the import._

Answer (score 0):

Looks when you create a new database, heroku automatically creates an app for you. Check it with `heroku list` So you can restore using the empty app.

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'dumped-db-secure-url' --app heroku-postgres-xxx
```