# copying data from refinerycms in heroku to apache hosted website

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, apache2, refinerycms

I have a website already hosted on `heroku`.I added all content in the remote refinery.now i hosted the same website on `apache` using `passenger`.And i want to copy the content from the heroku refinery to the apache one.How do i go about it?
my database.yml file is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
```

Im using ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your new database.yml file? or were you using mysql on heroku too (most people use postgres)?
working on the assumption that you were on postgres on heroku and want to move to a mysql local database you will first need to copy your database information onto your new server. 
For information on how to get the data off've your heroku database see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449893/how-to-backup-restore-standalone-heroku-postgres-database), the relevant line is here:

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Now you'll have a postgres backup file that will be all the sql commands needed to recreate the backup with all your data, you would think that since sql is a standard and mysql uses that too you could just do

```
mysql my_new_database_name < mydb.dump
```

Unluckily you're often not that lucky (I would recommend trying it, you never know with simple enough database structures) and you will then need to use a converter, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql) recommends using [pg2mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php).

This does of course bring up the question of why you want to move to a mysql installation?
Here is [an article by digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems) comparing sqlite, mysql and postgres, which has this to say about postgres.

> PostgreSQL is the advanced, open-source [object]-relational database
>   management system which has the main goal of being standards-compliant
>   and extensible. PostgreSQL, or Postgres, tries to adopt the ANSI/ISO
>   SQL standards together with the revisions.

For my own opinion I quite like postgresql and find it has less unpleasant surprises than mysql but YMMV. Given the extra work in switching databases I'd probably be inclined to stick to Postgres but that's my opinion.

Comment: ok, i have made the mydb.dump file. and just like you said mysql my_new_database_name < mydb.dump didnot work out.  pg2mysql requires me to copy-paste the contents of my .dump file there. but im not able to open it.so how do i copy-paste the content?

Comment: how do you open a .dump file?

Comment: when i opened it using sublime text i got a page full of 
5047 444d 5001 0c00 0408 0101 0100 0000
0019 0000 0000 2000 0000 000e 0000 0000
0800 0000 0003 0000 0000 7200 0000 0000
0000 0000 0400 0000 6d79 6462 0006 0000
0039 2e31 2e31 3300 0600 0000 392e 312e

Comment: Just reading here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html it says  the options -Fc outputs a custom file that is also compressed, if you want a plain sql file use -Fp. These features are mentioned in the documentation.